# How to compare 2 strings and determine if there is at least a 4 character change using php

Tags: php, regex

I need to be able to compare 2 strings like string1"qwerty1234" and string2"qwerty5678" and be able to determine if string2 has at least 4 characters changed from string1.

For example:
qwerty1234 and qwerty1235 only has a 1 character change.
qwerty1234 and qwerty5678 has a 4 character change.
qwerty1234 and qazxcv1234 has a 4 character change.
qwerty1234 and qwerty has a 4 character change.
qwerty1234 and asdf123%^& has at least a 4 character change.

```
if (strcmp($cur_password, $new_password) <= 3)
{
    echo "Your new password is too similiar to your old password!"
    echo "There must be at least a 4 character difference.  Try again."
    break;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why/how `qwerty1234 => qazxcv1234` has 4 char change ?

Comment: Because in string2 a is different than w in string1, z is different than e, x is different than r, etc...does that make sense?

Comment: I'm counting 6 diff chars

Comment: Yes, your right. I am wanting to ensure at least 4, but more is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the difference with the [`levenstein` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php):

> The Levenshtein distance is defined as the minimal number of characters you have to replace, insert or delete to transform `str1` into `str2`.

[Code](http://ideone.com/l0zcnh):

```
$s1 = 'qwerty1234';
$s2 = 'qwerty5678';
echo levenshtein ($s1, $s2); // => 4
```

Comment: dam it that was the one i was actually looking for. For options im leaving my answer, but this makes more sense in the context of the question.

Comment: Interesting! I forgot to enter the code I was working with, but i edited the original question...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: looks great, I will give that a try and let you know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: This worked perfectly, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

before some one else turns my comment in to an answer.

There is a function for this.

[similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) — Calculate the similarity between two strings

using your strings:

`echo similar_text('qwerty1234','qwerty5678');`  =6

if you want 4 you could -6 from the string length

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_split` to split string into arrays and then do `array_diff` to get the difference. `count` function will get you length of difference:

```
$s1 = 'qwerty1234';

$s2 = 'qwerty5678';

$diffLen = count(array_diff(str_split($s1), str_split($s2)));
//=> 4
```